# Save two forms data with OneToOneField in Django

Tags: python, django

i have two models

```html
class Client(models.Model) :
    
    Code_Client=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ......
```

and

```html
class Adr(models.Model) : 
    client = models.OneToOneField(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I created two forms: one for Client and another for Adr in order to use it in one template I could do that with no problem but when I try to save the data from both form it gives me an error

```html
        if form.is_valid() and form_Adr.is_valid():
            #pdb.set_trace()
            new_client=form.save()

            Adr0 = form_Adr.save(commit=False)
            Adr0.client= new_client
            Adr0.save()
```

the error is

Client: this field is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You have relation between Client and Adr.
Is similar to **Foreign key**.

`client = models.OneToOneField(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

This statement require that for every instance of Adr exists
only one Client. That's reason of Client field is mandatory.
Use something like

`Adr0.client_set.all()`

`[<Adr0: client>]`